# Will this situaton generate a warning from the browser?

Tags: web-server, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to set up a domain/server/page with a ssl certificate.

let's call it

https://page.domain1.com
this will contain in an iframe content from
https://page2.domain2.com

Will this situation generate warnings from the browser ? ( most comon used ones  )

Thanx

Comment: I dunno whether it scares the browser, but it certainly scares me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No warnings in Firefox 4, IE8 or Google Chrome -- as long as both urls are https